# Is this function O(n) even though it has 3 for loops?

Tags: big-o

I found a function that implements a minesweeper minefield given some bombs and the field size. I want to figure out the time complexity of the function in Big O Notation.

The function `mine_sweeper` takes an array of arrays called `bombs` along with the number of rows and columns `num_rows` and `num_cols` and returns the Minefield:

```
def mine_sweeper(bombs, num_rows, num_cols):
    field = [[0 for i in range(num_cols)] for j in range(num_rows)]
    for bomb in bombs:
        (row_i, col_i) = bomb
        field[row_i][col_i] = -1
        for i in range(row_i - 1, row_i + 2):
            for j in range(col_i - 1, col_i + 2):
                if (0 <= i < num_rows and 0 <= j < num_cols
                        and field[i][j] != -1):
                    field[i][j] += 1
    return field

# For example
# mine_sweeper([[0, 2], [2, 0]], 3, 3) should return:
# [[0, 1, -1],
# [1, 2, 1],
# [-1, 1, 0]]
```

Notes about the code:

- In the returned minefield a bomb is represented by a `-1`
- Otherwise the integer represents the number of bombs surrounding that location

Original question:

- Is this function `O(n)` where `n` is the number of bombs?

I think it is because even though there are 3 for loops only the first one, `for bomb in bombs:`, would run more times if the number of bombs increased. All the other instructions run in constant time or `O(1)`.

Edit:

As others have said in the comments and some answers, the variable to increase to figure out the time complexity shouldn't be the number of bombs but instead the number of cells.

I'm looking for answer that shows:

New questions:

- What variable should I increase without bounds?
- What is the Time Complexity represented in Big O Notation when using the above variable?

Comment: Even if it's O(n) where `n` is the number of bombs, it's not O(n) where `n` is the number of cells. And since the number of bombs can't exceed the number of cells, it's meaningless to have `n` be the number of bombs. Big-O notation is about what happens as something increases without bound and the number of bombs *can't* increase without bound.

Comment: can you clarify the contents of the 2D-array `bombs` please? How does it represent the playing field? Also what programming language is this?

Comment: Does the example help? `bombs` is an array of arrays that are in the format `[[row,col],...]`, the output array is what the minefield would look like if it were the given size with the given number of bombs.

Comment: It sure does :)

Answer (score 2):

Since the function defines `field = [[0 for i in range(num_cols)] for j in range(num_rows)]`

And there are at most as many bombs as cells in the field the complexity is `O(num_cols * num_rows)`

Simply for the sake of initializing the array.

If we analyse the rest of the function we have `bombs` for which `bombs.size <= num_cols * num_rows` must hold. The rest of the loop just executes `-1..2 == 3` operations `-1..2 == 3` times making it 9 operations.

With

```
 if (0 <= i < num_rows and 0 <= j < num_cols and field[i][j] != -1):
                    field[i][j] += 1
```

running in constant time.

So assuming the worst case of `bombs.size == num_cols * num_rows` the `bomb in bombs` part is O(9 * num_cols * num_rows) -> `O(num_cols * num_rows)` still holds.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume every statement (including access of items of lists) runs deterministically in constant time, then each inner for loop would have approx. 3x constant factor. Take their product and you get 9n; however, since the Big O notation only cares about limiting behavior it's equivalent to O(n), so you're right.

Comment: Since it's only about limiting behavior, he's wrong. The number of bombs can't exceed the number of cells. So there is a constant limit it cannot exceed. Hence it's O(1) if the number of cells is constant and it's not O(n) if the number of cells is variable.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz In ideal conditions, you're correct, but if we only regard the algorithm mentioned in OP its time would be proportional to number of items in `bombs`, whether there are duplicates or not.

Comment: That assumes a cell can have more than one bomb. Though possible, that's a very unlikely assumption given that he named the function "mine_sweeper".

Answer (score 0):

> Is this function O(n) ***where n is the number of bombs?***

Yes, it very much is, and yet isn't :-)

It is, because the two internal loops have absoultely *nothing* to do with the number of columns or rows. They simply iterate over the `previous/current/next` `row/column`, effectively making them constant time.

You've actually hit on an aspect of complexity analysis that most beginners miss:

> What is `n`?

There are many possibilities here: bombs, rows, columns, cells, or some product of those.

However, the use of bombs is *definitely* not correct because that itself is limited by the cell count. Assuming normal Minesweeper rules of at most one bomb per cell, the limiting factor is therefore the number of cells, so *that's* what you should be using for `n`.

Hence both the bomb-processing loop (with its constant-time body, see above) and the field initialisation:

```
field = [[0 for i in range(num_cols)] for j in range(num_rows)]
```

are ultimately limited by the cell count.

And, since two sequential (un-nested) `O(n)` operations are still `O(n)`, that's the complexity you have.

---

One point I'd like to raise though has to do with real-world implications. Complexity analysis is very good for working out what happens as inputs become large. This means things like sorting, where you may be required to sort twenty items or a hundred billion.

It is *not* so useful in a game like Minesweeper where you're most likely limited to a resolution of something like 3840x2160. Allowing for tiny cells of 20x20, that gives 192x108 or about 20,000 cells. That's something you're computers going to get through not before a blink of an eye but probably even before the signals from your autonomous nervous system *reach* your eyelid to begin the process :-)

Answer (score 0):

No. If `n` is the number of bombs, then `n` cannot exceed the number of cells. The amount of work done when `n` equals the number of cells is a fixed limit that the algorithm cannot exceed. Hence, if we assume the number of cells is constant, it's O(1).

If we assume the number of cells is variable, it's not O(n).

So there is no assumption that leads to the conclusion that this is O(n). (Other than that you named this "mine_sweeper" even though it is not the classic mine sweeper game/algorithm/problem in which no more than one mine may be in a given cell.)

Let's call R the number of rows and C the number of columns. In the traditional minesweeper, the number of bombs is some fraction of the number of cells, that is, the fraction of cells that contain bombs is constant. In this case:

1. The maximum number of bombs is R*C.
2. The outer loop iterates O(R*C) times.
3. The next loop iterates O(R) times.
4. The next loop iterates O(C) times.
5. So the overall algorithm is O(R^2 * C^2).

If N is the number of cells, it's O(N^2) if the probability of a cell containing a mine is constant. If, instead, the number of bombs is constant, then it's O(N), again where N is the number of cells.

Comment: I think the array specifies how many adjacent bombs there are

Comment: the bombs don't have to be adjacent, it's just the locations of a bomb in the format `[row,col]`